# single word for one who eats the same food all the time

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a single word for someone who always eats the same food?

E.g. Hard boiled egg for breakfast, tuna fish for lunch, chicken breast for dinner. Every day.

Comment: that's not the same food all of the time.  That's three entirely different meals.

Comment: If you eat [nothing but rabbit](http://old.qi.com/talk/viewtopic.php?t=25888&start=0&sid=b24b19117b7e34927c33d56f10dcd544) you'll die of malnutrition because there would be insufficient fat-based vitamins, etc. I'm pretty sure the same applies to bananas, but I can't find a link for that.

Comment: The giant Panda is ________: it eats only Eucalyptus leaves.

Answer (score 2):

[Monophagous](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monophagous) (adjective):

> feeding on or utilizing a single kind of food; especially :  feeding on a single kind of plant or animal

Also what you have described above is a monotonous food schedule.

There is a condition called  [sitophobia](http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com/sitophobia):

> Fear of eating due to the unpleasant symptoms (e.g., nausea, vomiting and abdominal pain) that follow eating due to chemotherapy (a feature of chemotherapy-induced anorexia);  Unlike anorexia, there is an appetite, but it is curtailed by the anticipated emesis and nausea.

You can use it with selective to form "selective sitophobia."

Source: http://medical-dictionary.thefreedictionary.com

Comment: If _monophagous_ sounds too much like _monotonous_, try ***monotrog***, from Greek τρώγω 'eat; chomp, munch'

Comment: Can we use this for people with the same routine of eating? I think this is only used in zoology.

Comment: Cool word, but I don't think it quite fits what the O.P. is asking for, except in a humorous context. _Monophagous_ seems to be more of a scientific term, not something that would generally be used to describe an ultra-regular daily diet.

Comment: It seems like a fine enough answer to me.  But either way, I suppose this is what you get when you put arbitrary restraints on expression (like "I want to express it with a single word!").

Answer (score 1):

Single food diet is called ***monotrophic diet*** or ***monodiet (mono diet)***.

Mono meal (or monotrophic meal) is mentioned as the same meal that you eat in a mono diet (or mono eating).

> ***monotrophic*** (adj) feeding only on one kind of food
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/monotrophic</sub>
>
> ---
>
> Eating only one food at a meal is known as a monotrophic meal. If all meals over a period of time consist of a single food, such as oranges or grapes or watermelon, this would be called a monotrophic or “mono” diet.
>
> <sub>Source: http://www.rawfoodexplained.com/application-of-food-combining-principles/mono-meals-and-mono-diets.html</sub>

From the same source above, article mentions your example as a **regular diet consisting of monotrophic meals**:

> I do not endorse the use of a monotrophic diet for extended periods or regularly for several days every week, nor do I endorse the regular or extended use of a diet consisting of all monotrophic meals, i.e., each meal consisting of a single food, e.g., one kind of melon for one meal, grapes for another meal, romaine lettuce for another meal, alfalfa sprouts for another meal.

---

There is also a colloquial term ***mono-luncher*** for the person who eats the same meal.

Here is an article about mono-lunching: 
<sub>http://www.smh.com.au/lifestyle/diet-and-fitness/rise-of-the-monolunchers-20130506-2j39g.html</sub>

Answer (score 1):

While it is much broader than diet, and not a single word,the phrase **[creature of habit](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/british/creature-of-habit)** describes (according to *Cambridge Dictionary Online*)

> someone who always does the same thing in the same way:
>   *My father's such a creature of habit - he always has to have a biscuit and a cup of tea at bedtime*

You might say *When it comes to meals, he is a creature of habit - the same foods every day.*

Comment: I think this is a better answer than the _mono-_ alternatives, considering that the example person eats eggs, chicken, and tuna everyday. My first thought was the word _regular_.

Comment: @J.R. Actually just modified my example to reflect there are multiple foods involved.

Comment: It's all a matter of interpretation, of course, and the O.P. has given us little to go on; however, I think _creature of habit_ fits perfectly. The way this man is described, I imagine that, not only does he eat the same foods every day, but he always does so from the same chair, he always cracks his egg open the same way, the tuna is always served on the same toasted wheat bread, etc. Very Phileas Fogg-like: _the tea and toast at twenty-three minutes past eight, the shaving-water at thirty-seven minutes past nine..._

Answer (score 1):

To add the answers already here, **stenophagous** describes animals that eat a comparatively small variety foods.

[Etymology from Wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/stenophagous#Etymology): Ancient Greek στενός (stenós, “narrow, limited”) + φαγεῖν (phageîn, “to eat”).

[Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/stenophagous) describes it as especially in regards to insects. [Collins](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/stenophagous) describes it as possibly even a single type of food.

Answer (score 0):

How about (coining) ***monovore***?